# EnableDependencyInjection in OData extension library

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata

Our service has been using ApiController with EnableQuery attribute and we were using System.web.http.odata (odata < 6). When we moved to new ODataControllers in Odata 6.0 dlls, we started getting error no non-odata route registered.

This got solved by using EnableDependencyInjection which apparently creates non-odataroutes containers.

My question is what could be the other side effect (security, route configuration) of calling this method.